# Illegal string offset in a function in PHP

Tags: php, function

I have this PHP function:

```
function editDatas($datas, $got, $to_find, $to_replace) {
    foreach($datas['datas'] as $key => $rows) {
        foreach($rows as $number => $row) {
            if($row['id'] == $got) {
                $datas['datas'][$key][$number][$to_find] = $to_replace;
                return $datas;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this call:

```
$datas = json_decode(file_get_contents('datas.json'), true);  
$datas = editDatas($datas, 'hotel_name', "value", 'My new hotel name');
```

My json is actually like this:

```
{
    "datas": [
        {
            "category": "General",
            "id": "hotel_name",
            "type": "input",
            "maxlength": "15",
            "size": "10",
            "label": "Hotel name",
            "help": "Hotel name",
            "value": "Rubi's hotel"
        },
        ...
```

I'm trying to replace some value in my json.

The problem I'm facing is this error:

```
Illegal string offset 'id' in line 33
```

Which is the following in my function:

```
if($row['id'] == $got) {
```

I do not understand why because the `id` is know.

Could you please help me to solve my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your function has one too many loops in it. Try this:

```
function editDatas($datas, $got, $to_find, $to_replace) {
        foreach($datas['datas'] as $key => $row) {
            if($row['id'] == $got) {
                $datas['datas'][$key][$to_find] = $to_replace;
                return $datas;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Think again how and where you are iterating.

```
foreach($datas['datas'] as $key => $rows) {
// $key is 0, 1, ... and $rows is the object
    foreach($rows as $number => $row) {
    // $number is category, id, type ... and
    // $row is General, hotel_name, ...
```

Knowing this you can rewrite your if to

```
if ($number == 'id' && $row == $got) {

}
```

Comment: Got now : `Illegal string offset 'value'`

Comment: @Renée This is exactly the same error as it was for `id` which suggests that you have another if that needs to be rewritten the same way (`$number=='value' && $row == ..`)

Comment: What about the @NaN answer. That's solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please print the array after json_decode using print_r function You will get your answer.